# "Influences" vs. "influencers"

Tags: word-choice, differences

I want to say :"Identifying influences in different categories is interesting for companies". By "influences" I mean people, who have influence in some categories. Should I use "influences" or "influencers"?

Comment: Identifying important people in key areas is of vital importance to companies.

Comment: Thanks, followed your advice. Still, interested in correct usage of these words. @EdwinAshworth

Comment: OK, you asked. Should I use "influences" or "influencers" [here]? I wouldn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best word is "influencers", when you are referring specifically to people.

The term "influences" is vague. It can denote not merely people, but also lifestyle, stuff, behavioral traits and phenomenal moments among others.

For a synonym, the word "motivator" can also be put to use.

EDIT (useful from comments):

"You are a nice influence, Mr. Anonym." 
In this sentence and such, we can easily use "influence" as the subject ("you", in this case) denotes a person anyway; hence it is clear what the term "influence" is referring to (not objects, but person).

However, in Tonven's case (the questioner's), the subject is vague. To ensure that the audience understand that Tonven is referring to people and not some pivotal stuff or moments, it is better to use "influencer" over "influcence."

Comment: The word *influencer* sounds very odd to me; I don't know that I've ever heard it.  I am not saying not to use it, but to keep in mind that it may sound odd to your audience as well.

Comment: "You are a nice influence, Mr. Anonym." In this sentence and such, we can easily use "influence" as the subject (you, in this case) denotes a person anyways; hence it is clear what the term "influence" is referring to (not objects, but person). However, in Tonven's case (the questioner), the subject would not be of any help. I just discovered it, by the way. Thanks for making me improve myself. @Anonym

Comment: Upon rereading the question, I have to agree that whether the influences are human or not is unclear.  *Influencer* would clear the issue up, but it still sounds off to me.  Perhaps *people who have influenced X* may work, though it's not a single word. @Calypto

Comment: The influences are human. @Anonym